# Python OpenCV2 createBackgroundSubtractor and BackgroundSubtractorMOG module not found

Tags: opencv, python-3.6

I am having Python 3.6.1

OpenCV Version 3.2.0

I am getting the below error with createBackgroundSubtractorMOG

```
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'createBackgroundSubtractorMOG'
```

When i replaced it with BackgroundSubtractorMOG, i also got the below error.

```
fgbg = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'BackgroundSubtractorMOG'
```

Comment: read this: http://answers.opencv.org/question/94448/module-cv2-has-no-attribute-createbackgroundsubtractormog/

Comment: I also tried cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG() and BackgroundSubtractorMOG() from the above link but still not working :(

Comment: Does it return an error message?

Comment: Yes, i am getting the error : AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'BackgroundSubtractorMOG'

Comment: It seems that the `OpenCV 3.2.0` you have is without the extra modules, `opencv_contrib`. You built it yourself or downloaded from somewhere? What's your OS?

Comment: I had installed using pip3.  Let me install opencv_contrib and try again